# What happened to Elizabeth Peralez' last messages?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

**WARNING**: This question and any answers will almost certainly contain spoilers for the Peralez' quest chain. Proceed at your own risk.

I completed the quest Dream On by telling Jefferson about the spy ring. Later, I got a string of panicked messages from him. Perhaps not what I expected, but no surprise that I couldn't contact him back.

A while after that, while doing other quests, I got some messages from Elizabeth, which I didn't read right away as I was mid-dialog. I figured I'd just open my messages later and read them, and probably have a reply option which would give a similar "CONTACT NOT FOUND" message as I got with Jefferson.

However, Elizabeth Peralez no longer appears in my contact list at all. I can't read the messages. I know this is the end of the quest line, and she's not going to respond to my messages, but I really would have liked to read her last message.

I'm assuming my game is just bugged out. I'm not worried about that. The quests are done. What I want to know is, **What was the text of Elizabeth Peralez' final message(s)?** Google searching gives me the vague gist of it, but I want the actual text. Even the Cyberpunk Wiki doesn't have the text transcribed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's her last message:

[image: Peralez last message (text follows)]

Message text:

> V, I know that it might seem like you're trying to help, but I'd rather that you just left us alone... otherwise things won't end well.
> Goodbye, V, and please - stay away. You've done enough already.

Shortly after she blocks you, you cannot find her contact or messages in your phone anymore.